# Using contentId in Live Tile XML to Override a Previous Tile

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to use contentId as described https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-tiles-schema in my tile XML. Below is an example of my XML.

```
<tile>
<visual version="2">
    <binding branding="name" contentId="@ViewBag.Code" template="TileSquare150x150Text01" fallback="TileSquareText01">
        <text id="1">@ViewBag.Name (@ViewBag.Platform)</text>
        <text id="2">@ViewBag.When1 @ViewBag.Destination1</text>
        <text id="3">@ViewBag.When2 @ViewBag.Destination2</text>
        <text id="4">@ViewBag.When3 @ViewBag.Destination3</text>
    </binding>
    <binding branding="name" contentId="@ViewBag.Code" template="TileWide310x150Text01" fallback="TileWideText01">
        <text id="1">@ViewBag.Name (@ViewBag.Platform)</text>
        <text id="2">@ViewBag.When1 @ViewBag.Destination1</text>
        <text id="3">@ViewBag.When2 @ViewBag.Destination2</text>
        <text id="4">@ViewBag.When3 @ViewBag.Destination3</text>
        <text id="5">@ViewBag.When4 @ViewBag.Destination4</text>
    </binding>
    <binding branding="name" contentId="@ViewBag.Code" template="TileSquare310x310Text01">
        <text id="1">@ViewBag.Name (@ViewBag.Platform)</text>
        <text id="2">@ViewBag.When1 @ViewBag.Destination1</text>
        <text id="3">@ViewBag.When2 @ViewBag.Destination2</text>
        <text id="4">@ViewBag.When3 @ViewBag.Destination3</text>
        <text id="5">@ViewBag.When4 @ViewBag.Destination4</text>
        <text id="6">@ViewBag.When5 @ViewBag.Destination5</text>
        <text id="7">@ViewBag.When6 @ViewBag.Destination6</text>
        <text id="8">@ViewBag.When7 @ViewBag.Destination7</text>
        <text id="9">@ViewBag.When8 @ViewBag.Destination8</text>
        <text id="10">@ViewBag.When9 @ViewBag.Destination9</text>
    </binding>
</visual>
</tile>
```

I have EnableNotificationQueue set to true and I am pulling in 3 tiles at once from my remote source, which works OK. However instead of overriding a previous tile with the same contentId, new tiles get added to the maximum stack of 5 allowed by EnableNotificationQueue.

What I'm wanting to achieve is when the update happens, to have the 3 previous tiles overridden with the new ones, not have new ones added to the stack. From reading the docs contentId should let me do this but its not working as intended.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this issue resolved by finding something deep in the docs. Basically contentId doesn't do anything and you have to Tag the tile notification. If you are hosting an ASP.NET webservice on Azure like I am you have to send in the tag as part of the HTTP Response Header.

I modified my controller to include HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("X-WNS-Tag", "yourtag") and any future tile notifications that come in with the same tag, override the previous one using that tag - which is the behaviour I was looking to achieve.